# Unknown provider: currentAuthProvider <- currentAuth on AngularFire v2 Firebase v3

Tags: angularjs, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make user login and go on from / route in my angularfire app. But, somehow I got Unknown Provider Error while I am in MainController.
Here is my work;

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['firebase', 'ngRoute']);
```

This the factory of firebaseAuth.

```
app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
  function($firebaseAuth) {
   return $firebaseAuth();
  }
]);
```

This is from [authenticating with routers](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/guide/user-auth.md#authenticating-with-routers) angularfire tutorial.

```
app.run(["$rootScope", "$location", function($rootScope, $location) {
  $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function(event, next, previous, error) {
    if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
      $location.path("/login");
    }
  });
}]);

app.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when("/login", {
    controller: "LoginController",
    templateUrl: "views/login.html",
    resolve: {
      "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
        return Auth.$waitForSignIn();
      }]
    }
  }).when("/", {
    controller: "MainController",
    templateUrl: "views/home.html",
    resolve: {
      "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
        return Auth.$requireSignIn();
      }]
    }
  });
}]);
```

In the login page I can sign in via google pop up and I can see the cookie in the browser.

```
app.controller("LoginController", ["$scope", "currentAuth", "Auth", function($scope, currentAuth, Auth) {
  $scope.auth = Auth;

  $scope.auth.$onAuthStateChanged(function(firebaseUser) {
    $scope.firebaseUser = firebaseUser;
  });
}]);
```

When I open "/" path, it fails and creating error like [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=currentAuthProvider%20%3C-urrentAuth%20%3C-%20MainController)

```
app.controller("MainController", [ "$scope", "$location", "$firebaseArray", "currentAuth", function($scope, $location, $firebaseArray, currentAuth) {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref();

    if (currentAuth == undefined || currentAuth == null) {
      $location.path('/login');
    }
}]);
```

Is there something wrong that I miss ?

Thank you.